# Linux: How to check the size of a file on ftp without downloading

Tags: linux, ftp

I downloaded some files from ftp. And now I want to know whether my files are complete. So I need to compare the size of files of mine with ftp.
For example,

```
ftp://ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR824/SRR824576/SRR824576.sra
```

How can I get the size of the file without downloading it in linux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have an CLI FTP client installed `ftp ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov` followed by `size /sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR824/SRR824576/SRR824576.sra` would do the trick.
*Note: Not all FTP servers support `size`.*

If you have cURL, you could use something like `curl ftp://anonymous:nopassword@ftp-trace.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/sra/sra-instant/reads/ByRun/sra/SRR/SRR824/SRR824576/SRR824576.sra --head` which will output some information (see below) for you to read or for your script to parse.

`Last-Modified: Wed, 10 Apr 2013 15:48:22 GMT
Content-Length: 899530433`